# Use Set-AzureWebsite to setup deployment from source control

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

We can setup deployment from source control using the `New-AzureWebsite` commandlet. How can we do the same to *existing* websites?

Ideally, I am looking for is a commandlet like this:

```
Set-AzureWebsite <websiteName> -GitHub -GitHubRepository <repoName>
```

There doesn't appear to be such a commandlet. Is there a way to do this with Azure PowerShell? I supposed I could just delete and recreate the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `New-AzureWebsite` to update the deployment from source control for existing sites.